# ifstream.eof() not evaluating to true in C++

Tags: c++, file, input, ifstream, eof

I am struggling a bit with understand the file input stream in C++. I have a code snippet as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream in("x.txt");

    bool done = false;
    do {
        string input = "";
        getline(in,input);
        int x1;
        int x2;
        in >> x1;
        in >> x2;
        cout << input << " " << x1 << " " << x2 << endl;
        in.ignore();
        if(in.eof()) {
            done = true;
            cout << "reached eof" << endl;  
        }
    } while(!done);

    return 0;
}
```

With the file x.txt reading as follows

```
task1
12
1313
task2
13
1414
[blank line]
```

Note the intentional inclusion of the blank line at the end of the input file. All this means is that the enter/return key was pressed after typing '1414'.

My expected output is

```
task1 12 1313
task2 13 1414
reached eof
```

But in actuality, the output is

```
task1 12 1313
task2 13 1414
 13 1414
reached eof
```

I understand that pressing enter within an input file generates an implicit newline character, and before using a statement like `getline(ifstream, string)` we should `ignore()` that next newline character. With that being said, why is ifstream.eof() not evaluating to true even though I `ignore()` the implicit newline character after '1414'?

Comment: `while(in >> x1 >> x2)`

Comment: Why aren't you testing the return value of `getline`? Same question for `in >> x1` and `in >> x2`? If you are having problems with I/O **check if the I/O worked**

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/981959 with a different (but still wrong) loop

Answer (score 2):

The `eof` flag isn't set until after you try to read beyond the end of the file. You should instead check the result after reading from the stream, perhaps something like

```
while (getline(in, input) && in >> x1 >> x2) {
    cout << input << " " << x1 << " " << x2 << endl;
    in.ignore();
}
cout << "reached eof" << endl;
```

Comment: He should probably ignore until `'\n'` as well, just in case there is extra white space at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the second loop the stream position is at the end, but does not set `eofbit` until you try to read more data. Let's consider what happens after the first two loops have run and you enter the loop for the third time:

You try to read a line:

```
    getline(in,input);
```

This reads nothing, because you've already reached the end of the stream, so it sets `eofbit` and because nothing was extracted also sets `failbit`.  But you don't check if a line was read, or if `input` is non-empty, you just blindly continue

You declare two uninitialized variables:

```
    int x1;
    int x2;
```

Then try to read again:

```
    in >> x1;
    in >> x2;
```

That doesn't even try to read anything, because `failbit` is already set, but you don't check it here either. `x1` and `x2` are unchanged and remain uninitialized.

Then you print out the uninitialized integers, which happens to print out the values from the *previous* loop because that's what happens to be on the stack:

```
    cout << input << " " << x1 << " " << x2 << endl;
```

This does nothing because `failbit` is set:

```
    in.ignore();
```

Now *finally* you check the stream state, but it's far too late to prevent all the problems above:

```
    if(in.eof()) {
```

You should be checking that I/O operations succeed, not assuming they do and then finding out much later they that there's a problem when it's far too late to do anything about it.

The way to check I/O operations is to test the stream in a boolean context, e.g. `if (in)`, you should **not** be checking for EOF because that doesn't get set until you get to the end of the stream and then try to read *again*.

Mike's answer shows the correct way to do it, but you should also read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/981959)

Comment: If he's already extracted the last character of the file (with the `ignore`), then the `eofbit` and `failbit` should be set in the `getline`, before the `in >> x1` is reached.

Comment: @JamesKanze, ah yes, I mistakenly ignored the ignore :) I did mention that it doesn't even try to do anything when `failbit` is set, I'll make that clearer